# Why is my form not submitting data to update my database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

First, thank you in advance for any help you all can provide :)

I am creating a website (add_product_form.php) that will prompt a user for information about a product in a form. It should then take that information and update a products table (add_product.php). However, when I click on the "Add Product" button it is not doing anything. It isn't throwing an error that I am seeing or anything.

I have done the following in trying to troubleshoot this myself, all to no avail:
Research forms and form submissions on w3schools
Compared my code to example code provided in Murach's PHP and MySQL 3rd edition

Here is the code for the add_product_form.php

```html
<?php require('../model/database.php');
include '../view/header.php'; ?>

<main>          
    
    <h1>Add Product</h1>
        <div id="aligned"
            <form action="add_product.php" method="post" id="add_product_form">

                <label>Code:</label>
                <input type="text" name="code" placeholder="Enter Product Code"><br>

                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Product Name"><br>

                <label>Version:</label>
                <input type="text" name="version" placeholder="Enter Product Version"><br>

                <label>Release Date:</label>
                <input type="text" name="releaseDate" placeholder="Use 'yyyy-mm-dd' format">&nbsp;&nbsp;Use 'yyyy-mm-dd' format<br>

                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                <input type="submit" value="Add Product"><br>            
            </form>
        </div>  
    
    <p><a href="index.php">View Product List</a></p>

</main>

<?php include '../view/footer.php'; ?>
```

And here is the code from the add_product.php site:

```html
<?php 
$code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'code');
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$version = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'version');
$releaseDate = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'releaseDate');

 // Validate inputs
if ($code == null || $code == false){
    $error = "Invalid Code, please re-enter";
    
} elseif ($name == null || $name == false){
    $error = "Invalid Name, please re-enter";
    
} elseif ($version == null || $version == false){
    $error = "Invalid Version, please re-enter";
    
} elseif ($releaseDate == null || $releaseDate == false){
    $error = "Invalid Release Date, please re-enter";
    
} else {
    require_once('../model/database.php');
    $query = 'INSERT INTO products
            (code, name, version, releaseDate)
        VALUES
            (:code, :name:, :version, :releaseDate)';

    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':code', $code);
    $statement->bindValue(':name', $name);
    $statement->bindValue(':version', $version);
    $statement->bindValue(':releaseDate', $releaseDate);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    
    include('index.php');
}

if ($error != '') {
    include('../errors/error.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Again, thank you all for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the closing bracket for `<div id="aligned"`. Add that and the form will submit.

```html
<div id="aligned">
    <form action="add_product.php" method="post" id="add_product_form">
    ....
```

Comment: @Charles Great! Please mark this answer as solved so it will close the question and help others with a similar problem.

Comment: I have a procedural question. If the above answer solved most of the issues but for some reason the information is still not being INSERT'ed into my database how do I go about asking for feedback on that? Should I append to this post or should I start a new question? Sorry, I am new to this...

Comment: @Charles You would open a new question. Stacking questions is frowned upon here.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't see in your add_product_form.php where you included add_product.php.  So, in other words, when the user hits the submit button in add_product_form.php, the browser sends the info to your server, which sends the info to your add_product_form.php page, but how would your server know how to 'handle' the submitted information unless you also include the add_product.php code in your add_product_form.php page?  That is one issue I see.